# JsonFilter unit tests work, but real scenario doesn't - content type appears wrong - what's going on?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, mime-types

I have used some JsonFilter ActionResultAttribute which uses newtonsoft.Json json converter to convert the json in the request into a real object.  This appears to work fine some some basic parameters, but isn't working for more complex, so i wrote a UT for it (yeah I should TDD, but prototypes always come first...).

The attribute class method:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.Contains("application/json"))
        {
            string inputContent;
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream))
            {
                inputContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            var result = JavaScriptConvert.DeserializeObject(inputContent, JsonDataType);
            filterContext.ActionParameters[Param] = result;
        }
}
```

Now for the unit test (uses Rhino):

```
ActionExecutingContext aec = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ActionExecutingContext>();
HttpContextBase c = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpContextBase>();
HttpRequestBase r = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpRequestBase>();
aec.Stub(x => x.HttpContext).Return(c);
aec.Stub(x => x.ActionParameters).Return(new Dictionary<String, Object>());
c.Stub(x => x.Request).Return(r);
r.Stub(x => x.ContentType).Return("application/json");
r.Stub(x => x.InputStream).Return(new MemoryStream(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(lookupParams)));

JsonFilter f = new JsonFilter();
f.JsonDataType = typeof(LookupParameters);
f.Param = "TestParam";
f.OnActionExecuting(aec);
```

Yes, it's not asserting anything, but rest assured, the json is converted as expected.  Now for the json string:

```
String lookupParams = "{\"FormID\":0,\"IDFieldID\":\"\",\"NameFieldID\":\"\",\"ReturnType\":\"html\",\"SearchText\":\"\",\"AdditionalParameters\":{\"CodeLevel\":1,\"Level1ID\":\"#AccountCodes_935ab17d-74f4-4f79-990f-07898bc98868 #Level1ID\",\"Level2ID\":\"#AccountCodes_935ab17d-74f4-4f79-990f-07898bc98868 #Level2ID\",\"Level3ID\":\"#AccountCodes_935ab17d-74f4-4f79-990f-07898bc98868 #Level3ID\"}}";
```

Now - I have stepped into this code when run from the site itself and the ContentType, ALWAYS appears to be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".. even though this is the case, the object (LookupParameters) seen in the ActionResult code itself is still populated with the correct fields! So is something filtering it before my filter gets to it??  It would appear so to me, as the object is correctly converted from json to a real object and my code never seems to be invoked.  This would be fine, but that one of the properties (AdditionalParameters) is a Dictionary and is always null.  For completeness here is the ActionResult code:

```
[JsonFilter(Param = "lookupParams", JsonDataType = typeof(LookupParameters))]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Find(LookupParameters lookupParams)
{
    Dictionary<String, Object> addPrms = lookupParams.AdditionalParameters;
    ....
```

You want the jQuery too? here it is:

```
    var json =
    {
        FormID: formId,
        IDFieldID: idField,
        NameFieldID: nameField,
        ReturnType: "html",
        SearchText: searchText,
        AdditionalParameters: adPrm // this is also a json format object
    };
    $.get(urlToAction,
        json,
        SomeFunctionIRun,
        "json");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - so I was being a d**k but now find that perhaps a json serialisation isn't what i want.  Let me quickly show the alterations:

The jQuery - rather than use get/post, we must use ajax to set the ContentType (i had assumed the json datatype on the $.post method sorted this, but that's for the return value! - DOH):

```
   $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST", // MUST BE POST
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(json), // HUH?? if i dont stringify it, it's just a form format
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // HAS TO BE application/json
        success: LoadEntityLookupDialog
    });
```

Now on the server side, obviously just set my action to accept POST and we're away.  What it shows is that post/get will attempt to convert the data in the request into the object type without any filters (useful even!), but if you want to post json in the data, you need to send a json string (actually makes perfect sense).

Is there a better jquery method for this?

Answer (score 1):

Where in your filter are you placing the breakpoint?  You should be placing it on the very first line:

```
if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.Contains("application/json"))
```

Your Controller action then has to be decorated:

```
[ObjectFilter(Param="data", JsonDataType=typeof(JsonBag))]
```

Your filter should be running, but if the contentType is set to anything other than "application/json" then the code in the filter will not run.  Does it stop on the breakpoint when you run the application, and not when you mock/test?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, the problem is that my filter OnActionExecuting override does indeed have the check for the contenttype "application/json".  The problem seems to be that the filter is hit after the request in the context has been translated by something else.  If I remove the attributes completely and just get/post some json data, the data is automatically converted into the object type.  What is doing this?

Comment: Sorry - to answer your last question there: Yes when I break in the test the content type is "application/json" (cos i forced it in the mock) and when I break using the app the type is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".  The only way that can be is if something has translated the request before my filter gets it.

Answer (score 1):

Add HttpContext.Request.InputStream.Position = 0; before your using statement there... Took me about 30 minutes to figure out why the request seemed blank.